# Poset complex of reverse ordering

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, simplicial-stuff, simplicial-complexes

This might be too easy but I cannot proof it easily. Any reference or hint will be great.

**Q: Suppose P is a poset in which every chain is finite and $\Delta P$ is the poset complex associated to it. (i.e. faces of $\Delta P$ are the chains of the poset.). Suppose I reverse the order in the poset and suppose it again gives me a poset say $\bar{P}$. Let $\bar{P}$ also has the property that every chain is finite. Does $\Delta P$ and $\Delta \bar{P}$ are homeomorphic.**

Simple examples shows me that the second one gives me a subdivision of the first one, but is it true in general. Thank's in advance.

Comment: There are a lot of "suppose" here... The reverse of an order is always an order, so you don't have to suppose that $\overline{P}$ is a poset, that's always true. Along the same lines: The chains of $P$ are the same as the chains in $\overline{P}$ so again the assumption that $\overline{P}$ has finite chains is not really an assumption, it's always true. And then we arrive at what @BorisNovikov said: Since the chains are the same, the complexes are the same (as simplicial complexes not just homemorphic). What was the question again?

Comment: This should be asked at mse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f:P\to \bar{P}$ is the antiisomorphism. It maps a chain $a_1<\ldots< a_n$ into $a_n<\ldots a_1$ so it maps every simplex into itself.